# Using getElementById to populate an element on page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Am new with Ajax but I know that you can use getelementbyid to update any element on the page with that id. What I want to know is how do you target a particular element on the page if they all have the same id?

```
<li class="a">something</li><li class="a">something b</li>
```

How do I target the second li? since they both using the same id, i cannot use getelementbyid('a') since this will only update the first element with that id.

This is my ajax script

```
function loadurl(dest) {
var XMLHttpRequestObject = false; 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new 
        ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp"); 
} if(XMLHttpRequestObject) { 
        XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dest); 
        XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() { 

    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && 
        XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
        document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = 
        XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText; 
        delete XMLHttpRequestObject; 
        XMLHttpRequestObject = null; 
        } 
    } 
    XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null); 
}
```

}

and this is link

```
<a onclick="loadurl('page.php?p=1&id=2')">
```

Comment: You should not reuse id's. That is why you are now struggling. To group elements use class names. Id's uniquely identify a single DOM element.

Comment: As a pointer: the reason that `getElementById()` has a singular name, as opposed to, for example, the plural name of `getElementsByClassName()`, is because it applies to, and should find/manipulate, ***only one*** element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same id more than once in an HTML page is invalid HTML. If you had used class names instead:

```
<li class="a">something</li><li class="a">something b</li>
```

then you could have used document.getElementsByClassName() to get an array containing all the elements with that class.

To put your response in the second element, use something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("a")[1].innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
```

or, to put your response in all of the elements with that class name, use something like this:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; ++i)
    els[i].innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
```

Comment: I changed the tag to class now! So how do I implement your technic to work with the code above?

Comment: thanx G, but does that means I have to enter the number (1) manually??? what if the LI is the 20th or 8th on the list??? How do you detect this and make sure the script picks this up?

Comment: This kind of begs the question, why would you want to? If you are trying to target a particular element, give it a unique id and use document.getElementById(). If you are trying to target several elements, give them a common class name and use the code to target all of them. Just what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: ok let me explain better. I have a bunch of items eg <li>some title</li><li>another title</li><li>yet another title</li> and lets say if I click on 'yet another title' it should change to read something else like "you've clicked on "yet another title" without page refresh!

Comment: Just give each a different id. <li id="a1">some title</li><li id="a2">another title</li><li id="a3">yet another title</li>. Pass the id to your function: <a onclick="loadurl('page.php?p=1&id=2','a3')">. Then modify your function to accept it: function loadurl(dest, targetId). Then use the parameter to target the element: document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;

Comment: OMG Gaurav...thanx a mil! That worked like a charm! You can take a look www.repjesus.com and like a post! Am also trying to ajaxify the entire website...think you can help with that??? Hit me up!

Answer (score 2):

Don't repeat IDs, use class names instead. IDs are meant to be unique.

```
<li class="a">something</li><li class="a">something b</li>
```

You could then use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) then, to select them.

```
$(".a")
```

Comment: Or you could use `document.getElementsByClassName('a');` and then a `for` (or other) loop to do the same thing. jQuery's not necessary for everything (as good as it really, really is...).

Comment: @David of course it's not, but it exists, so I suggest using it because it improves readability and it's really simple to use.

Comment: True, but I think the vanilla-JS approach would have been more applicable (with a library approach, jQuery, MooTools...) as an addenda, to show the differences and (perhaps) benefits of a library.

Comment: i hear you guys and thanx for the tip! But can someone please adjust my script above to accommodate the fix? Thank you.